# Whats wrong with this XSS vector?

Tags: xss, javascript, html, dom

**Payload:**

```
<DIV STYLE="background-image: url(javascript:alert('XSS'))">
```

**Reference:** http://seguretat.wiki.uoc.edu/index.php/XSS_Cheat_Sheet

Can someone please explain why this payload is not working?

Comment: no. that answer says this is not quite possible. But this vector is present in OWASP. If it doesn't work, then I will be happy to know "Why it doesn't". Which the answer you suggested hasn't explained

Comment: It does explain that. *The techniques to inject script code via CSS `expression(...)` or `url('javascript:...')` don't work in modern browsers.* Modern browsers simply do not accept `javascript:` urls when loading resources in CSS.